# Changing innerHTML only works once

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm attempting to make a scoreboard in HTML, where a javascript function can change the scores for various players.  However, the scores for all but one of the players don't display correctly.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scoreboard"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function Player(ID) {
    this.ID = ID;

    var scoreboard = document.getElementById("scoreboard");

    //Create a <p> in scoreboard with "Player n:" in it, and then
    //create a <span> with the score and a unique ID to use for getting and setting
    scoreboard.innerHTML += "<p>Player " + this.ID + ":" + "<span id=\"PlayerScore" + this.ID + "\">0</span></p>";

    this.scoreElement = document.getElementById("PlayerScore" + this.ID); //set score element

    //Getter and setter for score
    this.getScore = function() {return Number(this.scoreElement.innerHTML);}
    this.setScore = function(scoreIn) {this.scoreElement.innerHTML = scoreIn.toString();}
}
```

I test this code using the following Javascript:

```
var player1 = new Player(1);
var player2 = new Player(2);
var player3 = new Player(3);

player1.setScore(player1.getScore() + 1);
player2.setScore(player2.getScore() + 1);
player3.setScore(player3.getScore() + 1);
```

After doing this, the scoreboard in the generated webpage reads:

```
Player 1:0
Player 2:0
Player 3:1
```

However, it should read

```
Player 1:1
Player 2:1
Player 3:1
```

Any ideas?  Why does only the last one work?  Is it a problem with how I'm getting and setting directly from and to the InnerHTML of the scoreElement?  Does it have anything to do with my browser (firefox)?

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: every time you use `+=` on innerHTML, all the old elements are thrown away and new ones are inserted, so your links to the code below that point are broken. you can change the below code to use `scoreboard.children[id]`, but it would be better to create the P tag in js and append it rather than use innerHTML to add the dynamic content.

Comment: Really?  Because it certainly works fine for appending the new players on sequentially.  The only problem is updating the innerHTML of the spans afterwards.

Comment: you can add the players, then scan the container for elements and subscribe them at that point.

Comment: No because teh ` this.scoreElement` reference becomes stale

Comment: Your `this.scoreElement` refers to only the last ID as it is overwritten

Comment: it might be confusing in the devtools because the element still exists, but it's been removed from the dom, so updating it doesn't do much.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c90380yL/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is your use of `innerHTML` to append more content, once you use `innerHTML +=` it will recreate all the dom elements so your `scoreElement` references you created previously will no longer present in the dom tree that is why those are not getting updated.

The way to solve it is not to use `.innerHTML` to append content, instead you can create dom elements and call the appendChild() method to add it to the parent element like

```js
function Player(ID) {
  this.ID = ID;

  var scoreboard = document.getElementById("scoreboard");

  var playerElement = document.createElement('p');
  this.scoreElement = document.createElement('span');
  this.scoreElement.innerHTML = 0;
  playerElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Player " + this.ID + ":"));
  playerElement.appendChild(this.scoreElement);
  scoreboard.appendChild(playerElement)

  //Getter and setter for score
  this.getScore = function() {
    return Number(this.scoreElement.innerHTML);
  }
  this.setScore = function(scoreIn) {
    this.scoreElement.innerHTML = scoreIn.toString();
  }
}

var player1 = new Player(1);
var player2 = new Player(2);
var player3 = new Player(3);

player1.setScore(player1.getScore() + 1);
player2.setScore(player2.getScore() + 1);
player3.setScore(player3.getScore() + 1);
```

```html
<div id="scoreboard"></div>
```

---

As [@dandavis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis) said in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33210045/changing-innerhtml-only-works-once/33210239#comment-54224886), another tweak you can do is

```js
function Player(ID) {
  this.ID = ID;

  var scoreboard = document.getElementById("scoreboard");

  var playerElement = document.createElement('p');
  playerElement.innerHTML = "Player " + this.ID + ":" + '<span>0</span>';
  this.scoreElement = playerElement.querySelector('span');
  scoreboard.appendChild(playerElement)

  //Getter and setter for score
  this.getScore = function() {
    return Number(this.scoreElement.innerHTML);
  }
  this.setScore = function(scoreIn) {
    this.scoreElement.innerHTML = scoreIn.toString();
  }
}

var player1 = new Player(1);
var player2 = new Player(2);
var player3 = new Player(3);

player1.setScore(player1.getScore() + 1);
player2.setScore(player2.getScore() + 1);
player3.setScore(player3.getScore() + 1);
```

```html
<div id="scoreboard"></div>
```

Comment: i find it's easier to use, eg. `var p=document.createElement('p');` to get the object, but then use `p.innerHTML="<span> Player..."` on the rest to avoid all that dom mess...

Comment: This works perfectly, and works out to be a much cleaner implementation than trying to do tomfoolery with the innerHTML directly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the problem, every time you call the constructor, it rebuilds `scoreboard.innerHTML`, meaning all its child elements are deleted and rebuilt,

so only in your last instance, `this.scoreElement` dose not get rebuilt.

you could solve this either using [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or by `getElementById` every time you get or set the score

```js
function Player(ID) {
    this.ID = ID;

    var scoreboard = document.getElementById("scoreboard");

    //Create a <p> in scoreboard with "Player n:" in it, and then
    //create a <span> with the score and a unique ID to use for getting and setting
    scoreboard.innerHTML += "<p>Player " + this.ID + ":" + "<span id=\"PlayerScore" + this.ID + "\">0</span></p>";


    //Getter and setter for score
    this.getScore = function() {return Number(document.getElementById("PlayerScore" + this.ID).innerHTML);}
    this.setScore = function(scoreIn) { document.getElementById("PlayerScore" + this.ID).innerHTML = scoreIn.toString();}
}


var player1 = new Player(1);
var player2 = new Player(2);
var player3 = new Player(3);



player1.setScore(player1.getScore() + 1);
player2.setScore(player2.getScore() + 1);
player3.setScore(player3.getScore() + 1);
```

```html
<div id="scoreboard"></div>
```